# Snackbar shown in one activity only in Android application

Tags: android, android-activity, snackbar

My Android application using push notification and for every push there is snackbar message that shown in the bottom of the client screen, the problem is that I can see the snackbar in one activity and when the user navigate to another activity the snackbar disappear, there is a way for showing snackbar for all the activities of the application?

Answer (score 2):

> when the user navigate to another activity the snackbar disappear

Snackbar is shown in relation to view. Going to another activity removes the view snackbar was related to, so snackbar must be gone too. If you need context-less thing, use `Toast`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a global variable system to do that, you could set it up like this:

in your android manifest under the application tag put

```
android:name="com.company.nameOfYourApp.Globals"
```

next create a new class named Globals (or whatever you want to name it, but the last word in the above manifest addition must match it) and put in the global variable(s) you want to use in any of your activities, in your case you'd want an integer and a String such as:

```
package com.company.nameOfYourApp;

import android.app.Application;

public class Globals extends Application {

public int activateSnackBar = 0;
public int getData0() {
    return activateSnackBar ;
}
public void setData0(int activateSnackBar ) {
    this.activateSnackBar = activateSnackBar ;
}

     public String snackBar= new String;
     public String getData1() {
     return snackBar;
}
public void setData1(String snackBar) {
    this.snackBar = snackBar;
}
}
```

now in your activities method that creates your snackbar first put in this code to access your global variables:

```
Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();
```

then when your snackbar is created set the integer value to 1 and the String value to what your snackbar's text is like this:

```
g.setData0(1);
g.setData1("snackbar text");
```

Now in your other activity the user can switch to, in the onCreate method get the global variables and create your snackbar again by again putting

```
Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();
```

at the beginning of the onCreate method and accessing the variables with something like:

```
int showSnackbar = g.getData0();
String snackbarText = g.getData1();
if (showSnackbar == 1) {
// create your snackbar and fill it with the snackbarText
// then you can choose weather or not to reset the interger 
//variable so it wont keep showing up forever
}
```

hope that helps